# ListView Not Updating After Filtering, when the backspace key is entered

Tags: android, listadapter

Here is the code, I used a custom adapter, and applied the Filter method, now the ListView does not update when the backspace key is entered, on when one switches back from an item activity. please help me.. and how to display no result to filtered list..

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemVO>
{

    private ArrayList<ItemVO> itemList;
    private ArrayList<ItemVO> fiems;
    private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
    private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
    private Context context;
    private Filter filter;

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<ItemVO> stateList) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, stateList);
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = new ArrayList<ItemVO>();
        this.itemList.addAll(stateList);
        this.fiems=new ArrayList<ItemVO>();
        this.fiems.addAll(stateList);

    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null)
        {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v)  
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    ItemVO item = (ItemVO) cb.getTag();

                    item.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ItemVO state = itemList.get(position);

        holder.code.setText(state.getItemdescription());
        holder.name.setChecked(state.isSelected());

        holder.name.setTag(state);

        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        if (filter == null)
            filter = new PkmnNameFilter();

        return filter;
    }

    private class PkmnNameFilter extends Filter
    {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
            {   
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();  // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                String prefix = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0)
                {
                    ArrayList<ItemVO> list = new ArrayList<ItemVO>(fiems);
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                }
                else
                {
                    final ArrayList<ItemVO> list = new ArrayList<ItemVO>(fiems);
                    final ArrayList<ItemVO> nlist = new ArrayList<ItemVO>();
                    int count = list.size();

                    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
                    {
                        final ItemVO pkmn = list.get(i);
                        final String value = pkmn.getItemdescription().toLowerCase();

                        if (value.startsWith(prefix))
                        {
                            nlist.add(pkmn);
                        }
                       /*else
                        {
                           final Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context, "No Items Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                             Handler handler = new Handler();
                             handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    toast.cancel(); 
                                }
                         }, 1000);
                        }*/
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.values = nlist;
                    results.count = nlist.size();

                }
                return results;
            }



            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                itemList = (ArrayList<ItemVO>)results.values; // has the filtered values

                clear();
                int count = itemList.size();
                for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
                {
                    ItemVO pkmn = (ItemVO)itemList.get(i);
                    add(pkmn);

                    notifyDataSetChanged(); // notifies the data with new filtered values
                }
            }

        }


    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        boolean notifyChanged = true;
    }
    }
```

In main activity **for editetxt**..

```
 dataAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_items, itemList);

                    lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    final EditText searchBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.filter_text);
                   //searchBox.addTextChangedListener(this);


                    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);





                 // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
                    searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                            // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                            Log.d("Constants.TAG", "*** Search value changed: " + cs.toString());
                            CateringList.this.dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

                           dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                            //if(arg0.length()==0)
                           // {

                           // }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Why did you put notifyDataSetChanged(); inside for statement? Try to put it below for statement.

Comment: @Zoran, i did that.. but same problem occurs..when the backspace key is entered..listview not refresh.. plz help me

Comment: Can you post code for class that calls this adapter?

Answer (score 1):

You just need a validation if the ArrayList have data put it in your getView() method

```
if (itemList == null || itemList.size() == 0){
        //do your code here
      holder.code.setText("No Result");
    }
```

Brother change this line:

```
clear();
            int count = itemList.size();
            for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                ItemVO pkmn = (ItemVO)itemList.get(i);
                add(pkmn);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

To this:

```
itemList = (ArrayList<ItemVO>)results.values;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Try this one:

```
private ArrayList<ItemVO> mItemList;

public Filter getFilter()
{
    return new Filter(){
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                 final FilterResults oResults = new FilterResults();
                 final ArrayList<ItemVO> result = new ArrayList<ItemVO>();

                 If (mItemList == null)
                       mItemList = itemList;


                 if (constraint != null){
                      if (mItemList != null && mItemList.size > 0){
                          //loop
                          for (final ItemVO item : mItemList){
                          final String value = item.getItemdescription().toLowerCase();

                            if (value.startsWith(constraint.toString())){
                                    result.add(item);
                                 }
                          }
                       }
                  }
        }
       oResults.values = result;
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
                itemList = (ArrayList<ItemVO>)results.values;
                           notifyDataSetChanged(); 

  } 
}
```

Comment: No.it shows when filter occurs..and when the backspace key is entered listview not refresh.. plz help me

Comment: What do you want to show when the backspace is entered? and do your code works when the user input some data?

Comment: blank layout its for no result .. and its showing only search item.. after backspace key is entered..

Comment: No its not working.. when the backspace key is entered i want to show all items in that listview..

Comment: Do you change it like i told you above?

Comment: Where do you use that filter?

Comment: Thanks for this, your `mItemList` solved my issue after a good hour of searching. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because listItems of your adapter are removed, but when you press backspace, they are not added back. For example,you have total 10 items in recyclerview, when you press 'A' you get 4 filtered items. Here 6 items removed from your actual listItems( which had 10 items before). But these removed items never added back.

**Solution:** 
Check backpress and before filtering, make temp copy of you fullList First. And call filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i can help you. Try to change this:

```
CateringList.this.dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You access dataAdapter in two different ways, and also i think you don't need to call here notifyDataSetChanged, so put instead:

```
dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
```

Also, if you want to display list with no results rty:

```
dataAdapter.getFilter().filter("");
```

**EDIT :**

Add this code to listen for edit text changes:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {

        Log.d("Constants.TAG", "*** Search value changed: " + cs.toString());
        dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);       
};
```

And after initializing EditText put:

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Change this:

```
if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0)
{
    //ArrayList<ItemVO> list = new ArrayList<ItemVO>(fiems);
    results.values = null;
    results.count = 0;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

    itemList = (ArrayList<ItemVO>)results.values; // has the filtered values

    if(itemList != null) {
        clear();
        int count = itemList.size();
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            ItemVO pkmn = (ItemVO)itemList.get(i);
            add(pkmn);
        }

    notifyDataSetChanged(); // notifies the data with new filtered values
}
```

Comment: Is your onTextChanged called at all when you click backspace?  Does Log print anything when you do it?

Comment: ha but it shows like this..                                                          D/DTAG(4141): *** Search value changed: s
D/DTAG(4141): *** Search value changed: 
 D/DTAG(4141): *** Search value changed: u

Comment: I made another chage. I hope it will help you

Comment: i gives.... java.lang.NullPointerException.... because in publishresults i am using count..   int count = itemList.size();
                for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
                {
                    ItemVO pkmn = (ItemVO)itemList.get(i);
                    add(pkmn);

Comment: But here you removed that code. Either put if(itemList != null) {...} around it or remove that code. At the end leave notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1        at 
ItemVO state = itemList.get(position); We have to taken position of that items from getview method..

Comment: But where it happens? If it is in publishResults?

Comment: I edited code. Just as i explained, but you didn't do it, put  if(itemList != null) {...} in publishResults

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with this workaround... hope this one suit to you as well :)

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                        Log.d("Constants.TAG", "*** Search value changed: " + cs.toString());
                        CateringList.this.dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

                       dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                       dataAdapter.itemList = OriginalItemList;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                        //if(arg0.length()==0)
                       // {

                       // }
                    }
                });
```

before the search search text was changed... just assign back the original data state to the adapter to filter again.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call onQueryTextChange, just refresh the data to your recyclerview

```
    @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            
            rvAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(Context, <list of files>);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
            rvAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
```